# Is it possible to temporarily disable (turn off) a pool in Storage Spaces in Windows 10 or Windows 11?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, storage-spaces

My goal is to be able to use either a GUI interface or PowerShell script to temporarily disable or "turn off" a Storage Spaces pool, in either Windows 10 or Windows 11. But then re-enable it later, safely and reliably.

The purpose for this is to cause Windows to no longer see that pool, but then be able to cause Windows to again see that pool at a later time, usually separated by days or weeks. I am concerned that if I merely "remove" the pool, that recreating it later will either damage data or take a very long time.

My use case is that I intend to use said pool as an "archive" drive. A place to store large files that I will rarely need to access. Primarily for video and photography work. AND, I am trying to avoid building an entirely separate computer to use as a NAS device (which can then be turned off and on at will). I want to be able to "enable" the Storage Spaces pool, move or copy a bunch of files to it in one go, give Storage Spaces enough time to do all it's background stuff, then "disable" that pool again, just as if I had turned off a NAS, except it is all within the same case and powered by the same CPU as my main computer. You know, just to save space and clutter on my desk. Not to mention the hassle of building a separate PC.

Please assume I will be building a PC that is capable of running Storage Spaces, and that I am capable of determining how much space I need, and whether I want to use parity, etcetera. I am not terribly concerned with the performance of this setup, because it will just be for archival purposes. I am also aware of the need to match interleave size to block size properly. I cannot tell you exactly what the revisions of any operating system are, or the other specs of said computer, because this is all for planning purposes. Once I know what can be done, then I will know what I should build.

Comment: Storage Spaces simply wasn’t designed to do what you describe

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. If you make that a real answer, then I can upvote it.